# Python's os.path libraries equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, python, path

Let's say I have a binary in C# code ae /a/b/c/xyz.exe and it expects the /a/b/c/hello.txt in the same directory. How can I get the /a/b/c/hello.txt in full path?

In python, I can get the running program's path with `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])`, and I can get the directory info with dirname(), and I can use join() to have the new full path.

```
import sys
from os.path import *
newName = join(dirname(abspath(sys.arg[0]), "hello.txt")
```

How can C# do the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx), [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) and the classes in [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) to do the same things.  Your code would translate as:

```
// using System.IO;

string newPath = Path.Combine(
               Path.GetDirectoryName(
                     Path.GetFullPath(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs[0])
               ), "hello.txt");
```

This, however, will fail if the current directory has changed before you call this.  (It would in python, as well...)  It might be better to use the following:

```
// using System.IO;
// using System.Reflection;

string newPath = Path.Combine(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
               , "hello.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.StartupPath`

See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.71).aspx

Getting the current directory will fail if it's been changed since the program started.